# simple example of mxnet model parallelism

Tags: python, mxnet

The simple examples in the Guon tutorial for mxnet are very helpful to those of us who are just getting started with mxnet. As yet, there is not a simple example for model parallelism. I see the model parallelism example code for [LSTM](https://github.com/eric-haibin-lin/mxnet/tree/master/example/model-parallel-lstm), but I am new to mxnet and it would help me (and perhaps others) to have a more streamlined example. So, I have created a model parallelism example by working off the regression example in the gluon tutorial, and by mixing in some code from [mxnet.gluon.Trainer](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/gluon.html#mxnet.gluon.Trainer).

However, I am clearly getting something wrong. The gradients do not seem to be updated. Can anyone assist by identifying the problem(s)? The goal here is to create a linear regression model that has three layers, each held on a different gpu. The model itself is not useful, except as an example to show how initialization and training can occur for model parallelism, when using a custom block and imperative programming.

As I understand it, Trainer() is written for data parallelism. It will not work for model parallelism in that it requires all parameters to be initialized on all GPUs.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet import nd, autograd, gluon
from mxnet.gluon import Block

# make some data
num_inputs = 2
num_outputs = 1
num_examples = 10000

def real_fn(X):
    return 2 * X[:, 0] - 3.4 * X[:, 1] + 4.2

X = np.random.normal(0,1, (num_examples, num_inputs))
noise = 0.001 * np.random.normal(0,1, (num_examples))
y = real_fn(X) + noise
y = y.reshape(-1,1)

# configuration
hidden_layers = 2
num_gpus = hidden_layers + 1
ctxList = [mx.gpu(i) for i in range(num_gpus)]
#ctxList = [mx.gpu() for i in range(num_gpus)]

#os.environ["MXNET_ENGINE_TYPE"] = "NaiveEngine"
print("\n")

# ======================================================================
class myDenseBlock(Block):
    """
    A custom layer
    """
    def __init__(self, layer_number, size_input, size_output, **kwargs):
        super(myDenseBlock, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.layer_number = layer_number
        self.size_input = size_input
        self.size_output = size_output

        with self.name_scope():
            # add parameters to the Block's ParameterDict.
            self.w = self.params.get(
                'weight',
                init= mx.init.Xavier(magnitude=2.24),
                shape=(size_input, size_output),
                grad_req = 'write')

            self.b = self.params.get(
                'bias',
                init= mx.init.Constant(0.5),
                shape=(size_output,),
                grad_req = 'write')

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.as_in_context(ctxList[self.layer_number])
        with x.context:
            linear = nd.dot(x, self.w.data()) + self.b.data()
            return linear

# ======================================================================

# create net
net = gluon.nn.Sequential()
with net.name_scope():
    # initial layer, with X as input
    net.add(myDenseBlock(0,
        size_input = 2,
        size_output = 2))

    for ii in range(hidden_layers-1):
        net.add(myDenseBlock(ii+1,
            size_input = 2,
            size_output = 2))

    # final block, Y is nx1
    net.add(myDenseBlock(ii+2,
        size_input = 2,
        size_output = 1))


# ititialize paramerters for different blocks (layers) on different gpus.
params = net.collect_params()

"""
The parameters are:
sequential0_mydenseblock0_weight
sequential0_mydenseblock0_bias
sequential0_mydenseblock1_weight
sequential0_mydenseblock1_bias
sequential0_mydenseblock2_weight
sequential0_mydenseblock2_bias
"""

print("\ninitializing:")
for i, param in enumerate(params):
    if 'mydenseblock0' in param:
        params[param].initialize(ctx=ctxList[0])
    elif 'mydenseblock1' in param:
        params[param].initialize(ctx=ctxList[1])
    elif 'mydenseblock2' in param:
        params[param].initialize(ctx=ctxList[2])
    print("  ", i, param, "  ", params[param].list_data()[0].context)
print("\n")

def square_loss(yhat, y):
    return nd.mean((yhat - y) ** 2)

def mytrainer(updaters, params, ignore_stale_grad=False):
    #print("\n")
    for i, param in enumerate(params):
        #print(i, param, "  ", len(params[param].list_data()), params[param].list_data()[0].context)
        if params[param].grad_req == 'null':
            continue
        if not ignore_stale_grad:
            for data in params[param].list_data():
                if not data._fresh_grad:
                    print(
                        "`%s` on context %s has not been updated"%(params[param].name, str(data.context)))
                    assert False

        for upd, arr, grad in zip(updaters, params[param].list_data(), params[param].list_grad()):

            if not ignore_stale_grad or arr._fresh_grad:
                upd(i, grad, arr)
                arr._fresh_grad = False
                #print ("grad= ", grad)


batch_size = 100
epochs = 100000
iteration = -1

opt = mx.optimizer.create('adam', learning_rate=0.001, rescale_grad = 1 / batch_size)
updaters = [mx.optimizer.get_updater(opt)]

# the following definition for updaters does not work either
#updaters = [mx.optimizer.get_updater(opt) for _ in ctxList]

results = []
for e in range(epochs):
    train_groups = np.array_split(np.arange(X.shape[0]), X.shape[0]/batch_size)
    for ii, idx in enumerate(train_groups):
        iteration += 1
        xtrain, ytrain = X[idx,:], y[idx]

        xtrain = nd.array(xtrain)
        xtrain = xtrain.as_in_context(ctxList[0])

        ytrain = nd.array(ytrain).reshape((-1, 1))
        ytrain = ytrain.as_in_context(ctxList[0])

        with autograd.record():
            yhat = net(xtrain)
            error = square_loss(yhat, ytrain.as_in_context(ctxList[-1]))


            # Question: does the call to error.backward() go under the indent 
            # for autograd.record() or outside the indent? The gluon examples have 
            # it both ways

        error.backward()

        mytrainer(updaters, net.collect_params())

        if iteration%10 == 0:

            results.append([iteration, error.asnumpy().item()])
            print(("epoch= {:5,d}, iter= {:6,d},  error= {:6.3E}").format(
                e, iteration, error.asnumpy().item()))
```

The code fails at the "if not data._fresh_grad" test in mytrainer(). The output is:

```
initializing:
   0 sequential0_mydenseblock0_weight    gpu(0)
   1 sequential0_mydenseblock0_bias    gpu(0)
   2 sequential0_mydenseblock1_weight    gpu(1)
   3 sequential0_mydenseblock1_bias    gpu(1)
   4 sequential0_mydenseblock2_weight    gpu(2)
   5 sequential0_mydenseblock2_bias    gpu(2)

`sequential0_mydenseblock0_weight` on context gpu(0) has not been updated
```

I can verify using `mx.autograd.get_symbol(error).tojson()` that the computational graph only extends to the parameters on gpu(2), and does not reach other gpus.

Comment: Hi John. What version of mxnet do you use? I have tried to reproduce your error using mxnet version 1.0.0 and it seems to work fine - your test never fails. Can you check your version of mxnet and maybe update it to version 1.0.0?

Comment: Thanks much Sergei. I was using an older version of mxnet, and I can now verify that this test code works correctly using version 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, per @sergei's comment, moving to v1.0.0 solves this.